# How I know what is safe to delete in /mnt/yarn/usercache and /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers directories?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster running on AWS. I look in YARN and I see that 4 of my workers have this "unhealthy status" due to

```
1/2 local-dirs are bad: /mnt/yarn; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers
```

So, I ssh into the worker nodes -> run `df` and sure enough `/mnt/yarn` is at 99% disk spaced used. Also, a lot of the `stderror` and `stdout` files are taking up a lot of space in `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers` directory. My question is: what is safe to delete and what is not? I feel like I have been going down a rabbit hole and am still nowhere figuring out how to free up disk space in my worker nodes after reading for hours. I have been reading about `/mnt/yarn/usercache` directory, and it seems like the contents in that directory are "local resources" used to run my spark application. But `/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache` and `/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache` are taking up 3% and 96% of disk space, respectively, in `/mnt/yarn`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to clear this folder - /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs/

on HDFS. Try `hdfs dfs -ls /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs` to view it.

Another option to check - /mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers on executors.

There should be another folders with name like "application_someId". These folders contains logs for finished and running spark job.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can delete the container files in /mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers (as well as the log files in there).. I had a very similar problem.

I deleted the files, stopped and restarted spark on EMR and my unhealthy nodes came back.

Comment: AWS doc is very unclear about what you can and cannot delete.. but this works.